# Is constructor initializing the values or the CLR?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, clr

See my code below

My question is: I am not initializing the default value of `eId` and `eName`, but still the attributes get initialized to default values.

Is CLR doing this?

```
class Employee
{
    int _empId;
    String _eName;
    public Employee()
    {
        // I am not initializing the attributes here
    }
    public void Disp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id:: {0}  Name:: {1}", _empId, _eName);
    }
}

class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        new Employee().Disp();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All values and objects in .NET have default values. If you don't assign an explicit value, the default value will be used.

- For objects, the default value is `null`
- For value types, the [default value is 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) (or something that corresponds to 0, like `Guid.Emtpy`)

Since you don't initialize your fields with values, they get the default values.

Comment: I agree wit you, but I need to know wether CLR is doing the initialization when creating the memory ?

Comment: It does it when creating the variables. In this case, they are fields, so they're initialized when the object is created.

Comment: My next Question is.. If CLR does it by default when creating objects... What is the use of compiler creating a default constructor and initialize the values ?

Comment: The compiler creates a default constructor so that you can create instances of the class; e.g. so that you can write `var e = new Employee();` If `Employee` didn't have a constructor, you couldn't do that. It's just a convenience service supplied to you by the C# compiler; it has nothing to do with the CLR. In F#, for example, you always have to specify the constructor for a class, even if they constructor doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

> I am not initializing the default value of `eId` and `eName`, but still the fields get initialized to default values. Is CLR doing this?

Yes.

For classes, the memory allocator zeroes out the memory before the constructor is executed.

For structs, the runtime allocates a blank struct from the short-lived store, passes a reference to the temporary variable as `this` for the constructor, and then copies the value to the final destination. Note however that there are cases where the compiler and runtime can determine that the copy step can be elided without introducing a semantic change in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Class member variables that are set in the class definition are set before the constructor with default values. If you want, you can easily reset that default values in the constructor. Constructor is mandatory for class. If you are not created any constructor for the class the compiler will create the parameter-less constructor automatically. The automatically created constructor will not initialize the class member variables.

.NET has two data types (Value type and Reference type). Internally these two data types has its own default value. (Mostly reference types has default value as null). In your program you have used int and string data types. Int has '0' as the default value and string has 'Null' as default value. If you are not initialize the variable it will automatically takes the default value and process it.

Default values for value data types : [Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

Comment: I have explicitly written a constructor to initialize the values,,, but unfortunately I am not assigning anything.... Now Who is initializing the default values...? is CLR when creating memory  ???

Comment: Class member variables that are set in the class definition are set before the constructor with default values. If you want, you can easily reset that default values in the constructor. I forget to mention this in my answer. I updated it now.

Comment: "Class member variables that are set in the class definition are set before the constructor with default values."
Then why should compiler generate a default constructor to assign values if CLR is doing??